# Fluid inline svg that grows to occupy all empty space next to text in a flex row

Tags: css, svg, flexbox

I want to make an inline svg take all the free space in a row without specifying it's height on different breakpoints.

So the svg will have 100% height and a viewbox and will adjust itself to different screen sizes while preserving it's aspect ratio.

Here is some code and a non working pen code (the svg isn't taking the rest of the free space in the row):

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='text'>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
 <svg height='100%'>
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
</div>

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row .text {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 20rem;
}

.row svg {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRNPPR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the viewBox and no need to set `height:100%`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row .text {
  flex-basis: 20rem;
}

.row svg {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='text'>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 205 205">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
</div>
```

Or if you want to svg to grow you can try this:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.row .text {
  flex-basis: 20rem;
}

.row svg {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='text'>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 205 205">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how the shrink helps here?

Comment: @S.Schenk nothing :) it was in your code and i keep it ;)